# Pick a specific signature from a multi-signature function

Tags: typescript

Spent too much time on that one already. I have an interface with signature overloads, such as:

```
interface Foo {
  act(s: string): string;
  act(s: number): Promise<string>;
}
```

And I would need to extract only one of the declared signatures from it:

```
type strAct = Foo['act']// I need to extract ONLY the `(s: string): string` definition here
```

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: How do you want to select the desired overload ? By position ? By some of the parameter types ?

Comment: By return type. For this example, let say, pick only the overloads that does not return something that is extending `Promise`